# Can my wife use the ESTA line with me?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I have a German passport and use ESTA to enter the US, my wife has a regular visa

Can she use the ESTA line with me?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

There is no ESTA line.  Both you and your wife will need to use the "Visitors" line when entering the US.

If you have entered the US before on ESTA, then you may be able to use the US Citizen kiosks (it depends on the airport), however even if you are allowed use them then your wife will need to use the Visitor line as she is on a visa so you might as well use that line as well.

Comment: I would also suggest not going through a different line (kiosk, whatever) from your spouse. If there's any issues with entry, you do not want to be separated. I believe they would rather interview families together no  matter what line they're in.

Comment: @GregHewgill another reason not to go through separate lines: family members who travel together are supposed to submit a single customs declaration.